# When does a comment become off-topic?

Tags: discussion, comments

After answering OP's question, a sort of "don't mix this up with something else" comment is made that includes a small error cited from another source. Is trying to clear up this error off-topic? (And if so, isn't the original comment off-topic as well?)

Après avoir répondu à la question de l'OP, quelqu'un fait un commentaire genre « ne confondez pas ceci avec cela » qui inclut une petite erreur tirée d'une autre source. Est-ce qu'on considère une discussion de cette erreur comme hors sujet ? (Et si oui, le commentaire original n'est-il pas également hors sujet ?)

[Pourquoi utilise-t-on « si » dans la traduction : « Si on sortait ensemble ce soir ? » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16397/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-si-dans-la-traduction-si-on-sortait-ensemble-ce-so)

Answer (score 5):

Pointing out potential improvements in a post is exactly what comments are for. Quoting the [description of the comment privilege](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> You should submit a comment if you want to: (…)
>
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post

That being said…

[image: Duty Calls]

Sometimes you should just drop it.

---

Suggérer une amélioration potentielle dans un message est ce pour quoi les commentaires sont faits. Je traduis la [description du privilège « commenter »](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) :

> Écrivez un commentaire si vous souhaitez :
>
> - demander à l'auteur du message de clarifier quelque chose ;
> - offrir une critique constructive qui guide l'auteur vers une amélioration du message ;
> - ajouter une information mineure ou temporaire en lien direct avec le message, par exemple un lien vers une question similaire, ou encore pour signaler à l'auteur [d'une réponse] que la question a été modifiée.

Ceci étant dit...

[image: Duty Calls]

Des fois il faut savoir laisser tomber.